# Отступы между абзацами

Tags: drupal, html, css

Пишу содержимое на drupale. Вставляю вручную картинки. Почему то после картинок появляется тег <br>, который занимает место и добавляет отступ, этот тег виден если проинспектировать страницу, а в содержимом его нету. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать этот глюк и как задать вручную на html'e отступы между абзацами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p {margin-bottom: 10px;}

Comment: все равно промежуток остается,я хочу этот промежуток немного уменьшить

Comment: скриншот в студию

Comment: там ничего интересного просто отступ 1см межуд абзацами

Comment: Ну так я написал как это сделать. Не вижу никакой проблемы. А если у вас что-то не получается, будьте добры выложить код сюда http://jsfiddle.net. Угадывать никто здесь не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Получилось!

Если посмотреть в код страницы, то можно заметить, что на разных сайтах код абзаца установлен по умолчанию разный. Так, у меня это не `p`, а `br`. То есть предлагаемый выше код `p {margin-bottom: 10px;}` неверен!

Необходимо прописать `br {margin-bottom: 10px;}`, причем на разных сайтах у меня значение "прокатывало" разное. То удалось прописать `margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;`, то только `margin: 10px;`.

Также имело значение, в каком именно файле присутствует этот самый код, даже если кажется, что нашелся единственно верный вариант. Если не работает, то надо искать другие варианты.
Теперь во всех статьях имеются удобные для чтения отступы между абзацами - http://ob-eco.ru/5-oficialnye-stranicy-petra-poroshenko-v-populyarnyh-socialnyh-setyah.html

Answer (score 1):

```
p {
  text-indent: 1.2em;
}
```

Следует учитывать, на разные экраны человек смотрит с различного расстояния, и 1 сантиметр на мониторе компьютера и на смартфоне воспринимается по-разному. Например, когда установленный шрифт 2in, то 1em означает 2in. Также допустимо указывать процент, когда величина отступа рассчитывается в % от ширины блока текста.

Все нюансы описаны [здесь](https://domhtml.ru/abzacznyj-otstup-html/)